# How to add widget in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, widget, unreal-engine4, game-development

How can I add widget to the screen in Unreal Engine?
By some reason variable `blackLinesWidgetClass` is always null.

```
    FStringClassReference blackLinesWidgeClasstRef(TEXT("WidgetBlueprint'/Game/Blueprints/UI/blackLines.blackLines'"));
    UClass* blackLinesWidgetClass = blackLinesWidgeClasstRef.TryLoadClass<UUserWidget>();
    if (blackLinesWidgetClass)
    {
        UUserWidget* blackLinesWidget = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(this->GetGameInstance(), blackLinesWidgetClass);
        if (blackLinesWidget)
            blackLinesWidget->AddToViewport();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't very helpful, but I've always kept FAR away from trying to interface with doing widget stuff in C++, instead using Blueprint. Much less of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

.h

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> widgetBlackLines;
UUserWidget* widgetBlackLinesInstance;
```

.cpp

```
void AAct_31::BeginPlay()
{
    widgetBlackLinesInstance = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(GetWorld(), widgetBlackLines);
    widgetBlackLinesInstance->AddToViewport();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like UE4 isn't loading the class successfully from the class reference path you gave it. Try adding a `_C` here: `UI/blackLines.blackLines_C'"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
UGothicUE5DialogText* DialogText;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> DialogTextClass;

static ConstructorHelpers::FClassFinder<UUserWidget>DialogTextClassFinder(TEXT("/Game/UI/DialogText"));
if (DialogTextClassFinder.Class != nullptr)
    DialogTextClass = DialogTextClassFinder.Class;

if (DialogTextClass)
{
    DialogText = CreateWidget<UGothicUE5DialogText>(World, DialogTextClass);
    if (DialogText)
        DialogText->AddToViewport();
}
```